# Access Calculation not calculating consistently or correctly: "greater than" in IIF statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I created a MS Access database for tracking some items at work.  Users enter data which is then aggregated in queries (using count or sum) to calculate the actual value for each area, joined using UNION, then compared to goals for that area.  I attempted to enter an IIF statement to conditionally calculate the percentage of [Act]/[Goal], leaving it zero if [Act] is blank or 1 if [Act] is greater than [Goal] so there is nothing over 100%.  The issue is that it works most of the time, but other times fails with no obvious logic error or reason why that I can figure out.

Sometimes it can't tell that [Act] > [Goal] even though looking at it, it's obvious.  The numbers are all integers, nothing crazy or formatting differences.  The formula in [Met] is what I hope to achieve.  I added the [TEST] field to trace back where it might not be working, which shows Access just isn't always returning the correct answer to [Act] > [Goal].

My Query:
[image: screen]

What comes out (just the broken part):

[image: screen]

As you can see, it works correctly for most rows, but then thinks 149 is less than 52, and 128 is less than 3.  Because of this, it generates [Met] values over 100%.

Has anyone had this happen before or have any suggestions?  I have tried using refresh, clicking in the cell to hit enter, everything I can think of.

Comment: It won't let me edit (not enough points for the photos it contains?) 
The full formula for [Met] is:
Met: IIf(IsNull([Act]),0,IIf([Act]>[Goal],1,Round([Act]/[Goal],2)))
And the full formula for [TEST] is:
TEST: IIf([Act]>[Goal], "greater", "less than")

Comment: A good clue is in the query results window: text values are left aligned whereas numeric values are right aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that although your columns are Ints, they are being converted to strings in the variables (or at least one of the variables) Goal and Met.

If you look at the data, you'll see that if you compare them the results of Test are correct for a string comparison.

E.g. "3" > "128" (Because the first character has a higher char value).

In your query, try surrounding the variables with Val() when you are comparing them, as follows:

`IIf(IsNull([Act]),0,IIf(Val([Act])>Val([Goal]),1,Round([Act]/[Goal],2)‌​))`

Comment: Thank you!  I wondered if it was something like this based on a problem someone had in a different program, but wasn't sure how to test.  This fixed everything :)  Bonus points for explaining it clearly but still kindly.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: The source of your issue is, that union queries often return strings for numbers. You don't reveal your query, but read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910348/access-sql-appears-to-be-treating-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy/44921592#44921592).